# Auto detecting Baud Rate of Arduino

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I'm trying to detect baud rate of Arduino Mega2560 by using C#. My code is below:

```
SerialPort SP=new SerialPort();
SP.BaudRate = 115200;
```

BaudRate is specified as a constant like this, but I would like to automatically detect it.

For instance, if Arduino code includes Serial.begin(xxxx), program should declare SP.BaudRate = xxxx.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a C# programmer but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16590749/4138037) StackOverflow answer might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Note that to do this, there has to be a way to get an expected response from the device.

Comment: True, but you'll probably want some sort of basic handshaking anyway.